# Windows is not finding my file what to do?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-management

Here is my list of files  [image]

Here is the result of search   [image]

Also crossposted to  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/windows-is-not-finding-my-file/49909b75-da38-4f94-bb75-ccdcd47680e6.

I don't have index turned on but this seems ridiculous.  Also how do I know when a search is done?

Comment: You turn on indexing. That is what allows Windows to find your files

Comment: And if you search for `*2p4*` ?

Comment: This link has the most comprehensive info on search operators: [](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-advancedquerysyntax#query-operators). You can also specify the property you are searching to increase search efficiency. `~~` or `~=` is the *`value contains`* operator for strings, so you could use: `name:~~2p4`